# Suddently my peripherals devices(through thinkpad dock) stop being detected. And strange behaviour

Tags: usb, devices, thinkpad, dock

From few days ago, suddenly and randomly my devices disconnect through the thinkpad dock (all at the same time). Sometimes they connect again, but for the monitor (in i3wm) I have to restart the display server or execute xrand again.

Sometimes my mouse and keyboard aren't able to reconnect and I have to plug out and plug in directly on the thinkpad. (These two are connected to the dock with a Hubusb 2.0 (poor quality).

I noticed that sometimes it happens when I connect the keyboard or mouse.

I will try to change the usb port for the hub, see what happens.

My dmesg & journalctl, [here](https://gist.github.com/JorgeDLG/7c47246f93809f04f23c3cb665bfb393). 
Thanks in advance!

Update: I connect the monitor directly to the PC and the keyboard stills disconnecting, so it should be the dock. Maybe voltage things? I'm using 
 an unbranded 90W transformer. How can I check or 'clean / repair' it?

Update 2: Trying to isolate the issue, I only connect to the dock, the power cable and ethernet. Seems ok. I will be adding peripherals by little.

**Update 3**: It seems a hw problem. The dock is reconnecting all the port again and again. Look this [journal](https://gist.github.com/JorgeDLG/775071683bc0539634de43a9efb60f0b) and the lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 048: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo Lenovo ThinkPad Dock   
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:2118 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 058: ID 0000:0000 LENOVO                  Lenovo ThinkPad Dock   
Bus 001 Device 057: ID 17ef:1010 Lenovo Lenovo ThinkPad Dock   
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2386:340e Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Device number 48, why iterates so far?

When is suffering a constantly reconnections, if I move the power cable thats connects to the dock, seems to stabilize.

**Important think to my is determine if is a Software or Hardeware issue.**

Comment: I have made some grammar fixes. Please check that I have not changed any meaning (especially the bit about the keyboard and mouse).

Comment: On traditional (= non-USB3/Thunderbolt) laptop docks, the connector between the dock and the laptop may have many tiny contacts and might be located at the rear or bottom of the laptop. Any dirt in the connector might block some signals or cause the connector to fail to fully engage, causing an intermittent connection. I would recommend a careful checking and, if necessary, cleaning the dock connector before doing anything else. If the connector needs cleaning, remove the laptop battery if possible, and use tools that won't pick up static charge: a wooden toothpick might be good.

Answer (score 1):

The "all devices disconnect at the same time" strongly hints at a problem with the dock. Dirty/loose contacts? Flaky power?

Comment: It's a 2º hand dock but it's seems not damaged. How could I check if isn't broken?

Comment: @dlag, that is extremely hard to answer. There might be no physical (visible) damage, but some component can be broken (or just be borderline flaky, and just happens to malfunction with your machine and nobody else's). Short of a full diagnostic by a competent technician, I can't see how.